# Onde colocar código PHP que pega informações da máquina do usuário?

Tags: php

Criei algumas funções responsáveis por pegar o IP do usuário (e ISP, pais, browser, SO) a fim de manter um controle de quem acessa, de quantas vezes acessou em determinado minuto porem não sei onde inserir nas paginas de conteudo do site. Outra questão essa é a melhor forma de se pegar estes tipos de informação?

Código que pega as informações

```
<?php
    class ClientData{

        public $ip;
        public $isp;
        public $browser;
        public $so;
        public $city;
        public $country;
        public $referrer;

        /**
        *StartCatchData() 
        *Este método tem o objetivo de realizar todas as chamadas a métodos, obtendo 
        *assim todos os dados dos cliente.
        */
        public function StartCatchData(){
            $this->CatchIP();
        }

        public function CatchIP(){
            if(array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)){
                $this->ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];  
            }else if(array_key_exists('REMOTE_ADDR', $_SERVER)) { 
                $this->ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
            }else if(array_key_exists('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', $_SERVER)) {
                $this->ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]; 
            }else{
                $this->ip = false;
            }
        }   
    }
?>
```

Página de conteúdo

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Teste
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require_once 'ClientData.php';

    $clientData = new ClientData();

    $clientData->StartCatchData();
?>
Hello World!
</body> de exemplo:
```

Comment: "porem não sei onde inserir nas paginas de conteudo do site"? Inserir o que? As informações pegas ou o código? Você quer exibir os dados para o usuário?

Comment: inserir o código que aciona os métodos que capturam as informações do usuário, no meu exemplo coloquei logo abaixo da tag `<body>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sua duvida não é muito clara, mas se entendi tem dois "ambientes" possiveis:

> Recomendo usar include, require, etc antes de qualquer coisa, para manter a organização do projeto

1. Antes de renderizar:

   Execute antes da página ser completamente entregue ao cliente, pois o seu sistema necessita ter os dados mesmo do cliente conseguir ver qualquer coisa da página.

   ```
   <?php
       require_once 'ClientData.php';

       $clientData = new ClientData();
       $clientData->StartCatchData();
   ?><html>
   <head>
   ...
   ```
2. Depois de enviar o conteúdo todo

   Este processo deve ser feito se você necessita saber que o cliente já recebeu a página toda, por exemplo se você estiver criando um contador de download, o contador só deve "somar" quando o download for concluído:

   ```
   <?php
       require_once 'ClientData.php';
   ?><html>

   ...

   </html><?php
       $clientData = new ClientData();
       $clientData->StartCatchData();
   ?>
   ```

Comment: ,@GuilhermeNascimento essa é a melhor forma de se pegar estes tipos de informação?, e para verificar se estou sofrendo estou sofrendo DDOS está uma boa forma?

Comment: Este seu código não apresenta nenhuma questão de DDOS, portanto a minha resposta é baseada no uso do usuário e coletar dados apenas, se a sua duvida é sobre segurança você tem que especificar na pergunta. Realmente sobre DDOS, você pode trabalhar com PHP (e o primeiro exemplo é o melhor para previnir o ataque), mas você não precisa usar necessariamente o PHP contra DDOS, nem sei se é o melhor caminho, acredito que em servidores Linux por exemplo, você pode instalar aplicativos para prevenir isto, ou algum modulo pelo apache, vou me informar direito depois eu volto